# Optimizing MySQL Count query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a SQL Query that's taking over 3.5 seconds to return a count. Looking at the trace of the query it looks like all the indexes are being used. What can I do to optimize this to reasonable execution?

My thanks in advance.

---

[**Link to trace**](https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/86996/applications/553214/transactions?tw%5Bend%5D=1362600268&tw%5Bstart%5D=1362599693#id=100411964&app_trace_id=971064401&tab-detail_971064401=trace_details)

**SQL details**

**Query**

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `workorders`.id) AS count_all FROM `workorders` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.id = `workorders`.user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `assets` ON `assets`.id = `workorders`.asset_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` completed_by_users_workorders ON `completed_by_users_workorders`.id = `workorders`.completed_by_user_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `messages` ON messages.workorder_id = workorders.id LEFT OUTER JOIN `priorities` ON `priorities`.id = `workorders`.priority_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `suspension_reasons` ON `suspension_reasons`.id = `workorders`.suspension_reason_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_types` ON `job_types`.id = `workorders`.job_type_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `workorder_statuses` ON `workorder_statuses`.id = `workorders`.workorder_status_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `workorder_types` ON `workorder_types`.id = `workorders`.workorder_type_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `workorder_tasks` ON workorder_tasks.workorder_id = workorders.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `frequencies` ON `frequencies`.id = `workorder_tasks`.frequency_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `facilities` ON `facilities`.id = `workorders`.facility_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.id = `workorders`.location_id 
WHERE ((((workorders.workorder_status_id = ?)) AND (workorders.application = ?)) AND (workorders.facility_id = ?))
```

---

**Duration   3,791 ms
Query analysis (show details)**

**Trace**
**workorders**
The table was retrieved with this index: facility_id,app_fac,workorder_status_id
You can speed up this query by querying only fields that are within the index. Or you can create an index that includes every field in your query, including the primary key.

Approximately 33850 rows of this table were scanned.

**users**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY
Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**assets**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**completed_by_users_workorders**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**messages**
The table was retrieved with this index: workorder_id

Approximately 2 rows of this table were scanned.

**priorities**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**suspension_reasons**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**job_types**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**workorder_statuses**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**workorder_types** 
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**workorder_tasks** 
The table was retrieved with this index: index_workorder_tasks_on_workorder_id
You can speed up this query by querying only fields that are within the index. Or you can create an index that includes every field in your query, including the primary key.

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**frequencies** 
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**facilities**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

**locations**
The table was retrieved with this index: PRIMARY

Approximately 1 row of this table was scanned.

Comment: It might help to show the model that's creating this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you have bunch of `LEFT JOIN`s which don't affect final results ( you are selecting `distinct workorders.id` - I guess it's a PK column. Then only where is important , `WHERE ((((workorders.workorder_status_id = ?)) AND (workorders.application = ?)) AND (workorders.facility_id = ?)` . So I believe you can get rid of all `LEFT JOIN`s and write just select from 1 table making life of optimizer much easier ....

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_all
FROM `workorders`
WHERE ((((workorders.workorder_status_id = ?)) AND (workorders.application = ?)) AND   
(workorders.facility_id = ?)
```

The query above should give you the same result as your original query but with much less efforts.